# Is my circuit analysis correct?

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis

This is the circuit.

[image]

It is assumed that beta is 99 and VBE=0.7 V for both transistors.

Here is what I've done.

[image]

Multisim confirms the first set of values I worked out regarding Q1.
However it does not confirm the values for Q2.
What am I missing?

Comment: The \$Q_1\$ emitter current is: \$ I_{EQ1} = \frac{6V - 0.7V - 9V}{10kΩ + \frac{100kΩ||200kΩ}{\beta +1}} = 215.625\mu A \$ 

To solve it you could try to change \$I_{CQ1}\$ and \$R_{C1}\$ into a voltage source (source transformation). 

Or notice that \$R_{EQ1} = R_{CQ1}\$ thus we can assumed that \$V_{R_{EQ1}} \approx V_{R_{CQ1}}\approx 10kΩ * 215.625\mu A\approx 2.15V\$ (ignoring base current). Therefore \$I_{EQ2} \approx \frac{2.15V - 0.7V}{1k\Omega} \approx 1.45mA\$

Comment: @G36 base current cannot be ignored in this case. It is stated so in the exercise.

Comment: So you need to do the source transformation. \$V_{TS} = I_{CQ1}*R_{CQ1} = 2.135V\$ Thus, the Q2 emitter current is \$I_{E2} =\frac{V_{TS} - V_{BE2}}{R_{EQ2}+ \frac{R_{CQ1}}{\beta+1} }= \frac{2.135V - 0.7V}{1kΩ + \frac{10kΩ}{100} } = 1.3mA\$

Comment: MultiSim vs Falstad  https://tinyurl.com/yxmlqtsw both use fixed hFE so here I added Voltage probes everywhere and a slider for hFE2

Comment: Why do you calculate with such detailed accuracy when the beta is not used when transistors are saturated and the Vbe of each transistor is different?

Comment: Sorry guys   I had two  PNP's (Murphy's Law)  https://tinyurl.com/yyah6l8v   fyi   Falstad uses full precision but you can truncate decimal places in options.   OP may consider 2  significant figures only.  As Vbe is closer to 0.60V for 1mA  and 0.55V near 200 uA

Answer (score 2):

Q2's collector is not 'in parallel' with Q1's emitter.

If you don't include base current effects, then using the V calculated at the C of Q1 to see the V at the base of Q2, then calculate Q2's currents and V from just that.

Comment: Why is it not in parallel? Could you elaborate?

Comment: @kosgian90 The Q2 base is connected directly to the Q1 collector.

Comment: that's not what 'parallel' means. Present Q2 is not present; calculate voltages around Q1. now apply Q1's C voltage to a circuit with Q2 and its C and E resistors. That will get the correct answer except for some minor effects of Q2's base current on Q1's actual C voltage.

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to solve it. Here's the solution:

[image]

I spared you of showing all the math involved I just arrived at conclusions.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Why do you think that Q2 will be saturated in this circuit?

Comment: I mis-calculated, Vce2= 6.0V